# VBA - Get the content data table inside the JavaScript

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm having problem with getting td-content. It seems the data display using javascript, need to pull pictures data.

Table data:

[image]

Already try using the basic scrape, but can't collected the data.

VBA Code:

```
post = Trim(doc.getElementsByClassName("chart-content-container")(5).getElementsByTagName("table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")(1).innerText)
```

the data i want to get is from here (required login to see data, basically login using facebook):
[fanpagedata](https://www.fanpagekarma.com/facebook/ClashofClans#timesAndTypes)

html

```html
<div id="id1355">
<span class="chart-container" id="id12c4">
<div class="chart-title">Types of posts</div>
<div class="chart-content-container">
<div class="chart-content-sameInnerHeight" style="margin-top: 50px;" id="id1302">
<div id="id1355">
<div style="position: relative;">
<div id="dashboard9566356">
<div style="position: relative;" id="chartDiv9566356"><div style="position: relative;"><div dir="ltr" style="position: relative; width: 563px; height: 200px;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;" aria-label="A chart."><svg width="563" height="200" aria-label="A chart." style="overflow: hidden;"><defs id="defs"></defs><g><path d="M282,23.5L282,10A90,90,0,0,1,341.68103924167156,32.63403266460091L332.72888335542086,42.73892776491077A76.5,76.5,0,0,0,282,23.5" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" fill="#c2185b"></path></g><g><path d="M263.6923516820019,25.722950966907007L260.4615902141199,12.615236431655305A90,90,0,0,1,282,10L282,23.5A76.5,76.5,0,0,0,263.6923516820019,25.722950966907007" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" fill="#f57c00"></path></g><g><path d="M206.0577711314989,109.22105603953229L192.65620133117517,110.84830122297916A90,90,0,0,1,260.4615902141197,12.615236431655333L263.69235168200174,25.722950966907035A76.5,76.5,0,0,0,206.0577711314989,109.22105603953229" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" fill="#8ecbd3"></path></g><g><path d="M332.72888335542086,42.73892776491077L341.68103924167156,32.63403266460091A90,90,0,1,1,192.6562013311751,110.84830122297903L206.05777113149887,109.22105603953219A76.5,76.5,0,1,0,332.72888335542086,42.73892776491077" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" fill="#5c6fda"></path></g><g><g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="535" y="20.491718170580963" font-family="Arial" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#6d90cb">Links</text></g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="535" y="39.90828182941904" font-family="Arial" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#9e9e9e">11.5%</text></g></g><g><path d="M319.5,26.5L384,26.5L384,26.5L535.5,26.5" stroke="#636363" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="0.7" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path><circle cx="319.5" cy="26.5" r="2" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0.7" fill="#636363"></circle></g><g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="535" y="168.49171817058095" font-family="Arial" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#6d90cb">Pictures</text></g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="535" y="187.90828182941902" font-family="Arial" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#9e9e9e">61.5%</text></g></g><g><path d="M321.5,174.5L384,174.5L384,174.5L535.5,174.5" stroke="#636363" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="0.7" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path><circle cx="321.5" cy="174.5" r="2" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0.7" fill="#636363"></circle></g><g><g><text text-anchor="start" x="28" y="54.49171817058097" font-family="Arial" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#6d90cb">Videos</text></g><g><text text-anchor="start" x="28" y="73.90828182941904" font-family="Arial" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#9e9e9e">23.1%</text></g></g><g><path d="M209.5,60.5L180,60.5L180,60.5L28.5,60.5" stroke="#636363" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="0.7" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path><circle cx="209.5" cy="60.5" r="2" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0.7" fill="#636363"></circle></g><g><g><text text-anchor="start" x="28" y="19.491718170580963" font-family="Arial" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#6d90cb">Status</text></g><g><text text-anchor="start" x="28" y="38.90828182941904" font-family="Arial" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#9e9e9e">3.8%</text></g></g><g><path d="M268.5,18.5L180,18.5L180,25.5L28.5,25.5" stroke="#636363" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="0.7" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path><circle cx="268.5" cy="18.5" r="2" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0.7" fill="#636363"></circle></g></g><g></g></svg><div aria-label="A tabular representation of the data in the chart." style="position: absolute; left: -10000px; top: auto; width: 1px; height: 1px; overflow: hidden;"><table><thead><tr><th>Status</th><th>Wert</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Links</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>Pictures</td><td>16</td></tr><tr><td>Videos</td><td>6</td></tr><tr><td>Status</td><td>1</td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div><div aria-hidden="true" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 210px; left: 573px; white-space: nowrap; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px;">3.8%</div><div></div></div></div>
<div id="control9566356"></div>
</div>
<div id="id13ad" style="display:none"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">    var chart9566356; var data9566356;var options9566356;
var vAxisFormat9566356 = 'decimal';function drawVisualization9566356() {options9566356 = {curveType: 'none',  fontName: 'Arial',  'lineWidth':2,  'height':200,  backgroundColor: {  fill: 'transparent'  },'legend': {'position': 'labeled', 'alignment': 'center' , textStyle: {color: '#6d90cb'}},  chartArea: {   },tooltip :{ isHtml : 'true'},'interpolateNulls' : true, pieHole: 0.85, pieSliceText: 'none', chartArea: { width: '90%', height: '90%', left: '5%', top: '5%' }, series: {0: {targetAxisIndex: 0,areaOpacity :1.0,type: 'area',dataOpacity :1.0},1: {targetAxisIndex: 0,areaOpacity :1.0,type: 'area',dataOpacity :1.0},2: {targetAxisIndex: 0,areaOpacity :1.0,type: 'area',dataOpacity :1.0},3: {targetAxisIndex: 0,areaOpacity :1.0,type: 'area',dataOpacity :1.0}    },    vAxes: {      0: {format: 'decimal'},      1: {format: 'decimal'}    },colors: ['#c2185b','#5c6fda','#8ecbd3','#f57c00'],animation:{   duration: 500,  easing: 'out', },hAxis:{  textStyle: {  },gridlines: {color: 'transparent'},'baselineColor': '#ccc'},vAxis: {format: vAxisFormat9566356,  textStyle: {  },gridlines: {color: 'transparent'},'baselineColor': '#ccc'}    };
chart9566356 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chartDiv9566356'));
data9566356 = new google.visualization.DataTable();data9566356.addColumn('string', 'Status');    data9566356.addColumn('number', 'Wert');data9566356.addColumn({'type': 'string', 'role': 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}}); data9566356.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotationText'}); data9566356.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotationText'}); data9566356.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotationText'}); data9566356.addRows([['Links',3.0,'<div class="name">Links</div><div class="value">3</div>',null,'0','link'],['Pictures',16.0,'<div class="name">Pictures</div><div class="value">16</div>',null,'0','photo'],['Videos',6.0,'<div class="name">Videos</div><div class="value">6</div>',null,'0','video'],['Status',1.0,'<div class="name">Status</div><div class="value">1</div>',null,'0','status']]);
var numberFormatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ fractionDigits: 0 }); for (var i = 1; i < data9566356.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {  if(data9566356.getColumnType(i) === "number"){   numberFormatter.format(data9566356, i);  }}
var selectListener9566356 = google.visualization.events.addListener(chart9566356, 'select',function(){   var selection = chart9566356.getSelection();   for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {      var item = selection[i];      if (item.row != null && item.column != null) {var idsColumnNumber = item.column +2;var id = data9566356.getValue(item.row, idsColumnNumber);if(id != null) { id = id.replace('#', ''); } Wicket.Ajax.get({ u:  './ClashofClans?38-1.IBehaviorListener.0-fanPageKarmaPanel-resultContainer-graphenPanel-graphenTimesAndTypesPanelContainer-graphenTimesAndTypesPanel-content-postTypePanel-postTypePanel'+'&id='+id+'&datum='+data9566356.getValue(item.row, idsColumnNumber+1)+'&anzahl='+data9566356.getValue(item.row, item.column)+'&page_identifier='+data9566356.getValue(item.row, idsColumnNumber+2)+'&spalte='+item.column});     } else {        try {var id = data9566356.getValue(item.row, 7);           Wicket.Ajax.get({ u: './ClashofClans?38-1.IBehaviorListener.0-fanPageKarmaPanel-resultContainer-graphenPanel-graphenTimesAndTypesPanelContainer-graphenTimesAndTypesPanel-content-postTypePanel-postTypePanel'+'&id='+id+'&page_identifier='+id});         } catch(e) {            var id = data9566356.getValue(item.row, 5);           Wicket.Ajax.get({ u: './ClashofClans?38-1.IBehaviorListener.0-fanPageKarmaPanel-resultContainer-graphenPanel-graphenTimesAndTypesPanelContainer-graphenTimesAndTypesPanel-content-postTypePanel-postTypePanel'+'&id='+id+'&page_identifier='+id});         }     }   } });placeMarker9566356 = function(graph , dataTable) {
};placeMarkerListener9566356 = google.visualization.events.addListener(chart9566356
, 'ready',placeMarker9566356.bind(chart9566356
, chart9566356
, data9566356));
chart9566356.draw(data9566356,options9566356);}function reDrawChart9566356() { if (!$('#chartDiv9566356').is(':visible')) { return; } google.visualization.events.removeListener(placeMarkerListener9566356);
 placeMarkerListener9566356 = google.visualization.events.addListener(chart9566356
, 'ready', placeMarker9566356.bind(chart9566356
, chart9566356
, data9566356));
options9566356 = {curveType: 'none',  fontName: 'Arial',  'lineWidth':2,  'height':200,  backgroundColor: {  fill: 'transparent'  },'legend': {'position': 'labeled', 'alignment': 'center' , textStyle: {color: '#6d90cb'}},  chartArea: {   },tooltip :{ isHtml : 'true'},'interpolateNulls' : true, pieHole: 0.85, pieSliceText: 'none', chartArea: { width: '90%', height: '90%', left: '5%', top: '5%' }, series: {0: {targetAxisIndex: 0,areaOpacity :1.0,type: 'area',dataOpacity :1.0},1: {targetAxisIndex: 0,areaOpacity :1.0,type: 'area',dataOpacity :1.0},2: {targetAxisIndex: 0,areaOpacity :1.0,type: 'area',dataOpacity :1.0},3: {targetAxisIndex: 0,areaOpacity :1.0,type: 'area',dataOpacity :1.0}    },    vAxes: {      0: {format: 'decimal'},      1: {format: 'decimal'}    },colors: ['#c2185b','#5c6fda','#8ecbd3','#f57c00'],animation:{   duration: 500,  easing: 'out', },hAxis:{  textStyle: {  },gridlines: {color: 'transparent'},'baselineColor': '#ccc'},vAxis: {format: vAxisFormat9566356,  textStyle: {  },gridlines: {color: 'transparent'},'baselineColor': '#ccc'}    };
chart9566356.draw(data9566356,options9566356);}$('body').off('redrawAfterResize.chart9566356').on('redrawAfterResize.chart9566356', function() { reDrawChart9566356(); }); if (typeof googleChartApiLoaded !== 'undefined' && googleChartApiLoaded) {  drawVisualization9566356();} else {  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization9566356);}</script>
</div>
</div>
<p class="chart-footer-note">Here you can see the mixture of post types. Find out which types of posts are used most often in the selected time period. Generally speaking, it is good advice to try out all post types and entertain fans with a good mixture.</p>
</div>
</span>
```

Please, does anyone know how to scrape this?

Comment: you should include the html using the snippet tool via [edit] and more of your code.

Comment: That class name doesn't appear in the html provided

Comment: And what do you want to retrieve? What values?

Comment: pictures value, in those graph is value 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can gather all the td elements and loop testing for presence of the word `Pictures` then take node at next index:

```
Dim list As Object, i As Long
Set list = doc.querySelectorAll(".chart-content-container td")
For i = 0 To list.Length - 1
    If Trim$(list.Item(i).innerText) = "Pictures" Then
        Debug.Print list.Item(i + 1).innerText
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I am writing out to immediate window Ctrl + G. You can do post =  list.Item(i + 1).innerText

Comment: hi Qharr, yesterday i try it work, but today seem the site having a change in element maybe, and try again i can't pull the data